# Multiple dates with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

So this works, but I know it's not really the right way to do this. Can anyone give me some tips on writing this better? How would I write this more efficiently?

```js
// two weeks prior start
var date = new Date();
$('#twoWeeksPrior').text(get_last_date(date));

function str_pad(n) {
  return String('00' + n).slice(-2);
}

function get_last_date(date) {
  var y = date.getFullYear(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    day = date.getDate();

  // get date two weeks prior
  var result = new Date(y, m, day - 14, 0);

  return result.toLocaleDateString().split(",")[0]
}

// seven days prior start
var date2 = new Date();
$('#sevenDaysPrior').text(get_last_date_seven(date));

function str_pad(n) {
  return String('00' + n).slice(-2);
}

function get_last_date_seven(date) {
  var y = date.getFullYear(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    day = date.getDate();

  // get date one week prior
  var result = new Date(y, m, day - 7, 0);

  return result.toLocaleDateString().split(",")[0]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='twoWeeksPrior'></span>
<span id='sevenDaysPrior'></span>
```

Comment: This is a better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the getTime instead:

```js
let date = new Date();

// MILLISECONDS * SECONDS * MINUTES * HOURS
// One day prior is the amount of milliseconds in 1 day
let onedayprior = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
let oneweekprior = onedayprior * 7;
let twoweeksprior = onedayprior * 7 * 2;

$('#twoWeeksPrior').text(new Date(date.getTime() - twoweeksprior).toLocaleDateString());
$('#sevenDaysPrior').text(new Date(date.getTime() - oneweekprior).toLocaleDateString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='twoWeeksPrior'></span>
<span id='sevenDaysPrior'></span>
```